# VHDL implementation of pipeline calculating Y=A*B+C

Tags: vhdl

I have VHDL code, which implements `Y=A*B+C` pipeline in three stages, as illustrated below [image]

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity pipeline is
   Port (A : in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
      B : in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
      C : in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
      Y : out std_logic_vector (32 downto 0);
      CLK : in std_logic;
      RESET : in std_logic);
end pipeline;

architecture Behavioral3 of pipeline is
   signal OUT_A, OUT_B, OUT_C : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
   signal OUT_MUL_2, OUT_C_2 : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);

   begin
      Stage1: process(CLK, RESET)
         begin
            if RESET ='0' then
               OUT_A <= x"0000";
               OUT_B <= x"0000";
               OUT_C <= x"0000";
            elsif CLK ='1' and CLK'event then
               OUT_A <= A;
               OUT_B <= B;
               OUT_C <= C;
            end if;
       end process;

       Stage2: process(CLK, RESET)
          begin
             if RESET = '0' then
                OUT_MUL_2 <= x"00000000";
                OUT_C_2 <= x"00000000";
             elsif CLK ='1' and CLK'event then
                OUT_MUL_2 <= OUT_A * OUT_B ;
                OUT_C_2 <= x"0000" & OUT_C ;
             end if;
       end process;

       Stage3: process(CLK, RESET)
          begin
             if RESET ='0' then
                Y <= (others => ‘0’);
             elsif CLK ='1' and CLK'event then
                Y <= (‘0’ & OUT_MUL_2) + (‘0’ & OUT_C_2);
             end if;
       end process;
end Behavioral3;
```

**Question:** 
Why in the process "Stage3" the code is :

> Y <= (‘0’ & OUT_MUL_2) + (‘0’ & OUT_C_2);

rather than :

> Y <= OUT_MUL_2 + OUT_C_2;

**Wouldn't the implementation as written yield an OUT signal Y of always 0 (low), because anything&0 is always 0 and 0+0 is again 0 ?**

Comment: `&` in VHDL is concatenation

Comment: A-ha, so it prepends 0s to the 'interim' (Stage2) signal, but why is this necessary? I have this assumption, but is it correct: The '0' means -
 calculate the result and fill all the senior bits with 0s, so that any result from previous CLK is not getting in the way to yield incorrect result ?

Comment: It's just widening the current result. I'm not sure why though, all possible results fit in 32 bits, in fact Y only goes up to x"FFFF0000".

Comment: one thing: don't use `STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED` as it is non standardized. Either use `numeric_std` and the `unsigned` type. Or use `numeric_std_unsigned` if you stubbornly insist on using std_logic arithmetic...

Answer (score 2):

There is one point to take in account. Adders could be a signed adder. To avoid a misunderstood that a positive number on 32 bits is interpreted as a negative number, you can add a '0' bit before to be sure that the add will take in account 2 positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Y is the result of an addition of two words of 32 bits. This means Y must be on 33 bits in order to get the carry. So you add a '0' as MSB on your signals in order to compute this carry correctly and fit the result size.

Comment: There cannot be a carry. The product of two 16-bit numbers is at most x"FFFE0001", and that second 32-bit number is a zero-extended 16-bit number.

Comment: You're right but that's specific to this case. I think the person who implemented this circuit was used to make adders this way in order to manage the carry.